# Comparing CSV::Row objects to singleton nil vs using nil?

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-1.9.3

So I generate an array containing `CSV::Row` objects and nil as follows in Ruby 1.9.3-p374:

```
 csv_array = [nil, #<CSV::Row "name":John>, nil, nil, #<CSV::Row "name":John>]
```

The following line of code works fine:

```
 csv_array.delete_if { |x| x.nil? }
```

But this line gives an error:

```
 csv_array.delete_if { |x| x==nil }
```

Error:

```
.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:478:in `==': undefined method `row' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Any ideas on why this might be?  I thought `==nil` and `.nil?` would yield the same result.

Comment: I think the error is some where else.. please check your code..

Comment: Please give us the full stack trace..I am very much sure about that the error is some where else..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CSV::Row` overrides `==` and the implementation assumes that the thing you are comparing it to is also a `CSV::Row`. If you pass it anything that isn't of that class it is likely to blow up.

You could argue that this is poor practice, and that it should return false in this case rather than blowing up (this looks to have been changed in ruby 2.0)

`nil?` on the other hand has not been overridden and so works as you expect.

Comment: Thanks Frederick, no wonder!  Here's the link to the docs for 1.9.3 in case anyone is interested: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html#method-i-3D-3D

Answer (score 0):

> I thought ==nil and .nil? would yield the same result.

Yes they are giving. Look my below example:

```
require 'csv'

c1 = CSV::Row.new(["h1","h2","h3"],[1,2,3])
# => #<CSV::Row "h1":1 "h2":2 "h3":3>
c2 = CSV::Row.new(["h1","h3","h4"],[1,2,3])
# => #<CSV::Row "h1":1 "h3":2 "h4":3>
[nil,c1,c2].delete_if { |x| x.nil? }
# => [#<CSV::Row "h1":1 "h2":2 "h3":3>, #<CSV::Row "h1":1 "h3":2 "h4":3>]
[nil,c1,c2].delete_if { |x| x==nil }
# => [#<CSV::Row "h1":1 "h2":2 "h3":3>, #<CSV::Row "h1":1 "h3":2 "h4":3>]
c1.respond_to?(:nil?) # => true
c1.respond_to?(:==) # => true
c1==nil # => false
c1.nil? # => false
```

Your code,which you suspect as an error,is perfect. But from the line `'==': undefined method 'row' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`, it is much clear that,you used some where else in your code `something == something.row`, where that `something` is `nil`. Thus you got the error as `NilClass` do not have any `#row` method.